# Why are my packets going out the wrong interface according to the linux routing table?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have an Ubuntu Bionic machine with a wifi link; and I have set up a wireguard tunnel on it:

```
# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5502  bytes 545376 (545.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5502  bytes 545376 (545.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.0.0.3  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.0.0.3
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 22980  bytes 2777236 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 75  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 75
        TX packets 23467  bytes 12255956 (12.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 362 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.218  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
        ether dc:85:de:f3:3f:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 103227  bytes 54970550 (54.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 103695  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41654  bytes 15633577 (15.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I had previously been redirecting all traffic through the wireguard tunnel, but now I have reversed that to allow the peer to forward through this host. However, it seems like my packets still want to route through the tunnel for some reason.

Here's my routing table:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.1   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

If I try to ping or curl an external address, it always hangs. Traceroute shows that it's trying to route packets through the tunnel (the peer is currently configured to drop them):

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  68.393 ms  74.587 ms  74.328 ms^C
```

But if use `traceroute 8.8.8.8 -i wlan0` to force traceroute to use wlan0, as the routing table above should enforce, then it works.

What could be going on? Doesn't the routing table say that packets targeting 8.8.8.8 have to go out wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 for forwarding?

(In case it matters, my only iptables now are `-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT` and  `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`)

Comment: (1) Try `ip route get 8.8.8.8` to see if it's a routing problem, or somewhere else. (2) If it's a routing problem, have a look at the policy routing tables with `ip rule`. (3) Your multiple routes for 192.168.*.*/16 (is this REALLY a /16 ???) look very broken. I'd assume they don't hurt like this, but if you want to be sure, replace with one rule with the real netmask.

Comment: Thanks! `ip route get` said `8.8.8.8 dev wg0 table 51820` which clued me into the existence of extra, invisible routing tables which somehow take precedence over the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `wg-quick up` adds routes to another table which doesn't show up using `route -n` or `ip route show`. If you run `ip route show table all`, you can see it. In this case, it was in a table called `51820` and it was taking precedence over the default table.

Comment: So the next step is to find out what created those tables, and make sure they don't get created again.